# Login & OpenID workflow issue

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I wanted to upvote an answer. I wasn't logged in. Clicked on "log in", got logged in automatically and then I was at the "Add OpenID" page. Seems like a minor bug as the site is not aware I am logged in.

Comment: Which OpenID are you using?  Is this a computer you've never logged into before?  Which browser?

Comment: Yep, I see things like this all the time, the auto-login is kinda buggy.  I've learned after I dismiss the notification to always hit the questions button to verify that I'm really logged in.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this.

It is possible **if your browser is inappropriately caching the not-logged in page**, which would mean you ARE logged in, but the HTML displayed is from a previous load.